# What's the LINQ expression of this SQL code?

Tags: sql, linq

This is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM p
LEFT JOIN q ON p.id = q.id AND p.name = q.name
WHERE q.id IS null
```

I'm trying to convert this code to a LINQ expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from t1 in p
            join q1 in q on t1.name equals q1.name
            where q1.id == null
            select t1;
```

Comment: I used left join

Answer (score 0):

```
   var data = (from a in p
               from b in q.Where(x => x.id == a.id && x.name == a.name).DefaultIfEmpty()
               WHERE b.id == null
               select a).ToList();
```

Moreover you can try [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/) to convert your `SQL` query to `Linq`

Answer (score 0):

In general, assuming C#, convert SQL to LINQ by converting phrases in LINQ comprehension syntax order, and if SQL has table aliases, use them in LINQ as range variables.

It looks like you are trying to do a left anti semi join.

```
from pr in p
join qr in q on new { pr.id, p.name } equals { qr.id, qr.name } into qj
from qr in qj.DefaultIfEmpty()
where qr == null
select pr
```

It would normally be done like

```
from pr in p
where !qr.Any(q => q.id == pr.id && q.name.Equals(pr.name))
select pr
```